# IBM MQ - how to create a topic using REST API or SDK

Tags: java, rest, sdk, ibm-mq, jms-topic

There is a requirement to create a Topic in IBMMQ . I couldnt find any documentaion for creating a topic using rest-api or SDK . Kindly help to create a Topic in IBMMQ using REST API or Java SDK

Comment: Do you just want to publish or subscribe to a topic string,  or do you need to create s topic object?

Comment: I wanted to create a Topic object like the one mentioned below. thanks for your help @JoshMc

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MQSC REST API to create a topic. For example - do a HTTP/S POST to your MQ WebServer URL: `http://<MQ webserver host>:<port>/ibmmq/rest/v3/admin/action/qmgr/<qmname>/mqsc` with the following body:

```
{
  "type": "runCommand",
  "parameters": {
    "command": "def topic(RESTTOPIC) topicstr(RESTTOPIC)"
  }
}
```

This will create a topic for you.

Start your MQ WebServer using `strmqweb` and note down the REST API URL using `dspmqweb` command. Replace the URL in my example given above.

See [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=adminactionqmgrqmgrnamemqsc-post-json-formatted-command) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a ton Shashi. This really saved a lot of time and good learning

Comment: Glad!, I was of help. Would be great if you can accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: Hello Shashi. I have an another question. I am Trying to convert that REST API to java Code. but i am getting the below exception. Could you please help on this ?sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Or is there any SDK support to create Queue and Topics ?

Comment: Can you please another StackOverflow question with full details of what you are trying to do and full exeption stack? We at SO tend to keep one question per post. Thank you.